# Compiling some java files

Tags: java, eclipse, file, compilation

I am very unexperienced in Java, I and I have just messed up completelyIf you saw my first question I made here it talks about the bin folder. My question is how do I compile a java folder in eclipse but still be able to change the compiled folder? The problem is that eclipse compiles for you, but I deleted that by just being stupid so now I need my files compiled but I'm not done programing so I want to be able to change those compiled files. If you could shed any light at all it would really help thanks!

Comment: If I'm not wrong, eclipse will override the compiled files that need to be updated. If that doesn't happen, you can try cleaning your project (don't worry about deleting your bin folder)

Answer (score 0):

Disabling auto-compiling will solve your problem.

uncheck Project->Build Automatically. Then you have to write ant or maven script for special class files to be compiled.

http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-81_basics.htm

http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-helloworld.html

Comment: where would I write ant or maven script?

Comment: http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-81_basics.htm http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-helloworld.html

Comment: Ok I succsesfully compiled my files but I then tested to see if it would overide the compiled files and it didn't. Can you help me there too?

Comment: I have discoverd in the console that it says

Comment: Description Resource Path Location Type
Project 'Endevor' is missing required library: '\Rain\res' Endevor  Build path Build Path Problem
Description Resource Path Location Type
Project 'Endevor' is missing required source folder: 'Structures' Endevor  Build path Build Path Problem
Description Resource Path Location Type
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved Endevor  Unknown Java Problem